# Vue.js v-autocomplete v-model new data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

```
<v-autocomplete v-if="first.title == 'host'"
                :items="host"
                v-model="selected_host"
                item-value="host_n"
                outlined
                hide-details
                dense
              ></v-autocomplete>
```

I'd like to input new text which is not included in items.

autocomplete is just suggestion to user.
But I can't input new data in v-autocomplete. Whenever I write new data, it was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `v-combobox` ([doc here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)) instead of `v-autocomplete` if you want the user to add its own value

---

If you want to deal with multiple values, you can use the `multiple` attributes and passing an array to the v-model instead of a string (or an object if you use the `return-object` param)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
    tagsSorted() {
      return this.tags.sort()
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    host: [{
        host_n: 'Foo',
      },
      {
        host_n: 'Bar',
      }
    ],
    first: {
      title: 'host'
    },
    selected_host: ''
  }),

  methods: {
    sendData() {
      console.log(this.selected_host)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-combobox v-if="first.title == 'host'" :items="host" v-model="selected_host" item-value="host_n" item-text="host_n" outlined hide-details dense></v-combobox>
  <v-btn @click="sendData">Send data</v-btn>
</div>
```